# Regex for match a textual file

Tags: java, regex, file

I must create a regex for match the content of one file but I've one problem.
In this file I control that there are, for each line, this instruction:

> i=number j=number k=number u=number

But the difficulty is because I must match correctly also

> j=number i=number u=number k=number

and any disposition of i,j,k and u. 
How can I create one regex for all the cases? 
Note that there can be no any ripetition of i,j,k,u on the same line.
Thanks.

Comment: What is not working with your attempts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(([ijku]=)(?!.*\\2)number(?:\\s(?=\\w)|$)){4}`  will work for you. This handles repetition case as well.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String s = "i=number j=number k=number u=number";
    System.out.println(s.matches("(([ijku]=)(?!.*\\2)number(?:\\s(?=\\w)|$)){4}"));
    s = "u=number j=number k=number i=number";
    System.out.println(s.matches("(([ijku]=)(?!.*\\2)number(?:\\s(?=\\w)|$)){4}"));
    s = "u=number j=number k=number u=number";
    System.out.println(s.matches("(([ijku]=)(?!.*\\2)number(?:\\s(?=\\w)|$)){4}"));
}
```

O/P :

```
true
true
false
```

Comment: Thanks ;) 
But I don't understand this: (?!.*\\2) . What is it? Can you explain me? Thanks

Comment: @Antonio1996 It's a [backreference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to the second [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for checking by a negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) there is no `i=`...`i=`... You can also require the separating space by eg regex like: [`(?:(?:([ijku])(?!.*?\1=)=number) ){3}[ijku]=number`](http://fiddle.re/kpxdan)

Comment: @Antonio1996 - Yes, like *bobble* says, `\\2` means that its a *back reference* to the second captured group i.e, value between `()`s. Which is used to check whether there are any duplicate `<ijku>=` in the String

Comment: @bobblebubble - edited my answer to ensure that string ending with space is not matched.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called character classes:

```
[ijku]=number [ijku]=number [ijku]=number [ijku]=number
```

Comment: it still matches `i=number i=number`... etc

Comment: You should clarify if this is going to be used to validate or match only. @Antonio1996

Comment: In this case you should follow @TheLostMind's answer. That's it.